# Some badges on meta

Tags: discussion, support

I have a curiosity.
I see in the [badges page of meta.magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) a set of badges that in my opinion can't be earned.
Mainly all of them related to reputation points: Altruist, Benefactor,  Mortarboard, ...

Is this some kind of bug? Should those badges be listed there? Or there isn't a way to filter allowed badges per website?

Comment: You know, our 'meta' is not the most intense one. I guess some of those badges can be earned on SO meta.

Comment: @Tim. Yeah..I saw that the meta on SO is just like any other SO website, with it's own rep points. It's not the case here, that's why it seamed strange to me that those badges even exist here.

Comment: I don't think SE stuff will separate badges on per site basis, especially for websites which are still in beta.

Comment: Maybe I should ask this on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [an answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121923/224252) provided by [Bill The Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard). Not completely satisfying but it will do for now.

> I'd think that removing them would be even more confusing. Meta sites
>   are where you go to learn about a Stack Exchange site. As such, I
>   think we want all the badges listed there. The fact that some of the
>   badges can't be awarded on the Meta site is irrelevant. (There's one
>   badge that can't be awarded on Stack Overflow, but it's still listed
>   just for the sake of having a complete list.)